# Chrome Extension - Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I want to access contentDocument iframe inject any website using chrome extension.
which api from chrome extension develop can help?
Thank you

Comment: Take a look at these answers about accessing [cross origin iframe contentDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross+origin+iframe+contentdocument+answers%3A1)

Comment: I dont find any suitable answers for my questions.

Comment: Your question isn't clear then.